# Copy Date from Sheets to Documents with format

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using the following script to copy cells from a Google Sheets to a Google Docs List.
The first value is a date, how can I format to be dd/mm/yy? currently shows like this: Fri Jan 10 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST).

```
 function SheetstoDocs() {
      var headers = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get('1LJZIENPlfYGwAod3k3ky0XNd6F7L3GZ2Xtv0weUwzaU', 'A4:S4');
      var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('1LJZIENPlfYGwAod3k3ky0XNd6F7L3GZ2Xtv0weUwzaU');
      var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Pending');
      var vA=sh.getRange(5,1,sh.getLastRow(),sh.getLastColumn()).getValues(); //copia los valores
      var csh=ss.getSheetByName('Pending');
      var output=[];
      var templateId = '1B72yUdxPLsf1HZJzAHbG0u3yCO_a75L4D8QKzRqCzBg';
      var body = DocumentApp.openById(templateId).getBody()
      var getLastColumn = sh.getLastColumn();
      var getLastRow = sh.getLastRow();
      var u = 0;

      body.appendParagraph('')
      body.clear();

      for (var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
        output.push([vA[i][0],vA[i][1],vA[i][2],vA[i][3],vA[i][4],vA[i][5],vA[i][6],vA[i][7],vA[i][8],vA[i][9],vA[i][10],vA[i][11],vA[i][12],vA[i][13],vA[i][14],vA[i][15],vA[i][16],vA[i][17],vA[i][18]]);
        }


      while (vA[u][0] != "-") {
        for (var e=0;e<getLastColumn;e++) {

        body.appendListItem(headers.values[0][e] + ' | ' + output[u][e]).setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.BULLET);
      }

        body.appendPageBreak();
          u = u + 1;
      }
        }
```

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your situation, when `getValues()` of `var vA=sh.getRange(5,1,sh.getLastRow(),sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();` is modified to `getDisplayValues()`, can you get the result you expect? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues)

Comment: @Tanaike perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer:

*Rather than using `getValues()` in*

```
var = sh.getRange(5,1,sh.getLastRow(),sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
```

*you should use method `getDisplayValues()`.*

#### More Information:

`getDisplayValues()` returns an array of the values of the range, but with the same format as the way that the text is displayed in the UI - in the case of dates and times, it will return the display values rather than Unix/Epoch time or `Date()` objects.

#### References:

- [Google Apps Script - `Range.getDisplayValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues)